# Jquery ajax validate or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm using this code to execute an action in my controller with parameters. and currently working in validation of inputs.

```
$('.txt-dtr').on('blur', function () {
    // Record type to know what column of table should the value saved.
    var record = $(this).attr('id');

    // Record value 
    var value = $(this).val();

    // Record date
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var date = row.attr('id');

    // Employee id
    var empId = $('#sEmployee').val();

    // Ajax script for saving record
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/dtr/savedtr',
        data: {
            record: record,
            value: value,
            date: date,
            empId: empId
        }
    });
});
```

This code works, but `onblur` and i did'nt type anything in `txt-dtr` the `value` parameter is null and the ajax will not execute (which is actually what i want).

The question is, do i need to write a validation like

```
if(value != null){
    //execute ajax
}
```

Or leave it as is because even without validating it the ajax will not execute?

EDIT:

My controller is not accepting null values so that the ajax will not be executed if it has a null parameter value.

```
public ActionResult SaveDTR(string record, int value, DateTime date, int empId)
{
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you needs as Ajax wont validate. It will send null value

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use this validation, assuming that there should not be any null values.

```
   if(record !="" && value !="" && date!="" && empId!="")
    {
           //ajax code here
    }
```

You can also add validation on the page '/dtr/savedtr'.

Comment: Even without that validation the ajax will not execute which is what is want.

Comment: The question is do i need to write a validation like that? even without that validation the ajaxx will not execute.

Comment: If the controller is not accepting null values, you do not need validation like that. However, write a validation code to let user know some fields are not filled before sending it to controller.